# How to change principal text font size in latex report

Tags: size, latex, font-size

Hi I am using the following packages, I tried different methods to change the font size but in vain (`extsize`, `luximono`, `anyfontsize`). These are the packages I use (quite a lot actually), I suspect that one package is interfering in the process. If you can help, thank you.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[scaled=0.87]{luximono}
%\usepackage{extsizes}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{mathdesign}
\usepackage{lmodern,textcomp}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{here}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{titlesec}
%\usepackage{subfigure}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\bf\huge}{\thechapter}{2pc}{}
\usepackage{lastpage} 
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,epsfig,epstopdf,titling,url,array,xpatch}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
```

Comment: Precisely I want to change the default font size of 10pt to 7pt

Comment: There's a website dedicated entirely to [tex/latex](http://tex.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 2):

There is an easy global way to make it: `\fontsize{X}{Y}\selectfont` sets the default font size to `X`pt and the `baselineskip` to `Y`pt (`Y` should be about 1.2 times `X`).

Here is a minimal working example for your case, where I cut all the packages not dealing with our purpose but I left your title formatting (this latter is not affected by `\fontsize`).

```latex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\bf\huge}{\thechapter}{2pc}{}

\begin{document}

\fontsize{7}{9}\selectfont

\chapter{Example}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Vivamus at lorem vel felis consectetur hendrerit ut nec neque.

\chapter{Example}

Sed eget nunc leo. Nulla efficitur neque diam, aliquet interdum dolor gravida nec.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

In latex the default size is passed as an option to the documentclass, so that other document elements get appropriate sizes too.  The standard documentclasses only support `10pt`, `11pt` and `12pt`.  The `extsizes` package changes this.  Here is an example: use the `extreport` class instead of `report` and pass the size as an option as follows.

```
\documentclass[7pt]{extreport}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\section{A section}
\label{sec:section}

Some text in my report.

\end{document}
```